# Style radio buttons symfony

Tags: radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to style some radio buttons that are in a list but when I declare `input["type=radio"]{ border-style: none; }` in the CSS file it does nothing.
Here is the code where the radio buttons are:
`<?php echo $form['servico_id']; ?>`.

The servico_id is a list with six radio buttons options from the form new.
Can you help me? I hope I've explained myself well.
Thank you

the form newSuccess:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('marcacao/'.($form->getObject()->isNew() ? 'create' : 'update').(!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? '?id='.$form->getObject()->getId() : '')) ?>" method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
<?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="put" />
<?php endif; ?>
    <div id="sub-titulo">Dados Pessoais</div>
        <div class="sombra">Nome
        <?php echo $form['nome']; ?>
        <?php echo $form['id']; ?>
        <?php echo $form['_csrf_token']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sombra">E-mail
        <?php echo $form['email']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sombra">Contacto
        <?php echo $form['contacto']; ?>
        </div>
<div id="sub-titulo">Prefer&ecirc;ncia Hor&aacute;ria</div>
        <div class="sombra"> Dia<?php echo $form['dia']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;  Hora<?php echo $form['hora']; ?></div>
<div id="sub-titulo">Servi&ccedil;os</div>
    <?php echo $form['servico_id']; ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Marcar >"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing Symfony does for you is to render the buttons but if you inspect your html the code is the standard one. Do you have Firebug? Have you tried to add "!important" to your css rule?

Comment: Not the template, the resulting HTML ! So we can see wether the fault is in your form class or css selector.

Comment: here it is a bit:
<div class="sombra">
<div id="sub-titulo">Preferência Horária</div>
<div class="sombra">
<div id="sub-titulo">Serviços</div>
<ul class="radio_list">
<li class="mySpecialRadio">
<input id="feasy_marcacao_servico_id_4" class="mySpecialRadio" type="radio" checked="checked" value="4" name="feasy_marcacao[servico_id]">
<label class="mySpecialRadio" for="feasy_marcacao_servico_id_4">Acumpuntura Médica</label>
</li>
<li class="mySpecialRadio">
<li class="mySpecialRadio">
<li class="mySpecialRadio">

Comment: Ok, i assume this is only a breakdown of your html, cause <li><li> is not correct ! You'll find your answers in the fiddle i've created (http://jsfiddle.net/domi27/EDXFx/). Also updated my se-answer !

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are putting JQuery selector syntax in your css file. This is not 
correct. Instead either tag your `input type="radio"` elements with a CSS class and style that class in your css file, or add a javascript block to style your elements using jQuery.

ie. CSS file:

```
input.radio {
    background-color: blue; //style as you wish
}
```

ie. HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" /> Yes
<input type="radio" class="radio" /> No
```

**Or the alternative way (using JQuery/Javascript):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("input:radio").css('background-color', 'blue);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for aswer. it doesn't work too :( because its made in symfony and don't have "access" to the <input type="radio"... lines.

Comment: Ok sorry I'm not familiar with symphony. Note that you can just style "input" and it will affect radio, but this may negatively affect other input types. Did you try the second way? If you can add the javascript/jquery script it should work around the issue.

Comment: Thank you anyway. The thing is that all the other input tags are being styled but radio buttons aren't... there in a list and I cn style <li> but not the radio buttons. I've tried the second way too. Not sure if i used it right but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Post your css here (or the relevant pieces) so we can check it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the css... the problem is how do i get the radio buttons from the code i have... symfony generates the forms by itself so this kind of code is not showed.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it with symfony like this  :

1. Give your radio input a css class within the symfony form configure() function

   ```
   $this->widgetSchema["myradio"]->setAttribute("class" => "mySpecialRadio");
   ```
2. Put your styling in corresponding css file

   ```
   /* If you use ul/li rendering of sfWidgetFormChoice */
   li.mySpecialRadio {
       color: red;
   }

   input[type="radio"].mySpecialRadio {
       float: right;
   }
   ```

Comment: can i use it like this?
    $this->widgetSchema['servico_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('FeasyServico'), 'add_empty' => false, 'method' => 'getDescricao', 'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => true), array('class' => 'mySpecialRadio'));

Comment: Yes, this should work. You'll get a ul with li's containing your form inputs - all with css class "mySpecialRadio" !

Comment: unless i'm doing something wrong, it didn't work... I don't know what is the problem here :(

Comment: Please give show your resulting form html, so i/we can check the css selector !